# Using Google Sheets, how can I create a query that will output a '0' if a value doesn't exist?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R0zYMAigDULzm8oM2icsPK55BP162kVvctpx2cOSOIE/edit?usp=sharing) where I am entering Groceries on each row every time I visit a store.

[image]

I have created a query to output the sum for each store for all rows. This works great.

```
=QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  SUM(B) 
  where B is not null
  GROUP BY C 
  LABEL C '', SUM(B) ''")
```

[image]

Now I would like to use pretty much the same query, but I would like to limit it to only sum the entries that are from the past six months. This is my query:

```
=QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  SUM(B)
  where date '2016-08-28' < A
  GROUP BY C 
  LABEL C '', SUM(B) ''")
```

[image]

This works great as well, except I would like to have it list ALL the stores and if there are no entries for a store (such as Bristol Farms and Safeway in the example), then instead of omitting it I would like for it to display as 0.

So I would like for it to display like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind an extra column (you could hide it), on you spreadsheet, put this in J9:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A9:A13>Date(2016,8,28),B9:B13,0))
```

And this in K11:

```
=QUERY(A9:J13,"select C, sum(J) group by C order by C label sum(J)''")
```

I couldn't get Max's answer to work with sum. Maybe you can.

Comment: Interesting solution! Thank you! How do you hide a column?

Comment: Just click the column header (J), click the arrow and from the drop down click Hide column.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

I think, skipping rows with zero results is natural behaviour of `query` function. My suggestion is to use second query with opposite condition and with no headers.

### **Workaround**

**Step1. Original query**

Suppose we have small table, like this:

```
Name    Sum
Ma       10
Mu       20
Mo       30
Mi       40
```

The task is to get all rows with cum > 10:

`=QUERY({D83:E87},"select Col1, Col2 where Col2 > 10")`

result is:

```
Name    Sum
Mu       20
Mo       30
Mi       40
```

**Step2. Opposite query**

Let's make another query with opposite condition:

`=QUERY({D83:E87},"select Col1, 0 where Col2 <= 10 label Col1 '', 0 ''")`

The result is:

```
Ma        0
```

In this query:

- `select Col1, 0` gives zero for all rows
- `label Col1 '', 0 ''` skips headers

**Step3. Combination**

Last thing to do is to combine the formula into single array `{}`:

`={QUERY({D83:E87},"select Col1, Col2 where Col2 > 10");QUERY({D83:E87},"select Col1, 0 where Col2 <= 10 label Col1 '', 0 ''")}`

The result:

```
Name    Sum
Mu       20
Mo       30
Mi       40
Ma        0
```

Bad thing about provided solution is zeros will go in the end of the result.

---

In your case the final formula is:

```
={QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  SUM(B)
  where date '2016-08-28' < A
  GROUP BY C 
  LABEL C '', SUM(B) ''");
  UNIQUE(QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  0
  where date '2016-08-28' >= A and A is not null  
  LABEL C '', 0 ''"))}
```

I used `unique` function because Google Sheet SQL doesn't include `distinct` optoin.

The result:

```
Ralphs           120
Walmart          350
Bristol Farms      0
Safeway            0
```

The other way to get uniques and zeros is this formula:

```
={QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  SUM(B)
  where date '2016-08-28' < A
  GROUP BY C 
  LABEL C '', SUM(B) ''");
  QUERY(A9:C, 
  "select C,
  sum(B) - sum(B)
  where date '2016-08-28' >= A and B > 0
  group by C  
  LABEL C '', sum(B) - sum(B) ''")}
```

- `sum(B) - sum(B)` gives zeros
- `group by C` gives uniques
- `where date '2016-08-28'` is to get opposite condition
- `and B > 0` is used to cut empty results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max! I really want to have it only show the last six months of data though, so I need to add that condition to the WHERE clause. When it checks for the last six months, it will omit all the entries that don't have anything for them during that time period. Instead of completely skipping those though, I would like to have them listed as 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've added formula for your sample.